# How to get maximum value of one table based on value from another table

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I have two tables with data

Table A in yyyy-mm-dd and region (only west,east possible)

```
effect_date  region
2013-01-01   west
2013-01-02   west
2013-01-10   west
2015-01-01   west
2015-01-02   west
2015-01-10   west
```

Table B in yyyy-mm-dd (starts from 2015-01-01 to currentdate without gaps in dates)

```
run_date
01-01-2015 west
01-02-2015 west
.
.
.
03-27-2015 west
```

Now i want maximum of Table A which is less than each row of Table B. Sample output should be

```
2013-01-10   2015-01-01 west
2015-01-01   2015-01-02 west
.
.
2015-01-02   2015-01-10 west
2015-01-10   2015-01-11 west
```

I am not sure how to iterate for each row of Table B and my query is

```
select max(effect_date), region from TableA b join TableA a on a.region = b.region where effect_date < run_date; --returning only 1 row
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This field of problem is called groupwise maximum -- internet has a lot of literature on it.

Comment: thanks..will go through for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second table has no gaps, then you can use a join and cumulative maximum:

```
select a.*,
       max(a.effect_date) over (partition by b.region
                                order by b.run_date
                               ) as effect_date
from b left join
     a
     on b.run_date = a.effect_date and b.region = a.region;
```

Comment: Thanks Linoff for the answer